# how to define a measure as a multiple of another measure

Tags: f#

I am attempting to define `Isaron` to be `43.2` times an `Egg`, but I am getting an exception:

```
[<Measure>] type Egg
[<Measure>] type Isaron = (43.2)*(Egg)
```

> error FS0618: Invalid literal in type

**How do I correctly define this measure?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define the relationship in the measure type, you define it in functions that convert to and from the types:

```
[<Measure>] type Egg
[<Measure>] type Isaron
let toEgg (i : float<Isaron>) = i / 43.2<Isaron> * 1.0<Egg>
let toIsaron (e : float<Egg>) = e / 1.0<Egg> * 43.2<Isaron>
```

[Scott Wlaschin's site](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/#conversion-between-units) has another example of how to do it in feet and inches, by creating a constant conversion factor:

```
[<Measure>] type Egg
[<Measure>] type Isaron
let isaronsPerEgg = 43.2<Isaron/Egg>
let toEgg (i : float<Isaron>) = i / isaronsPerEgg
let toIsaron (e : float<Egg>) = e * isaronsPerEgg
```

Comment: You can define relationships between UoM types in the types themselves; multiplication, division and exponents work just fine. Coefficients just don't happen to be possible.

Comment: TeaDrivenDev makes a good point. If you follow my link to Scott Wlaschin's site, you'll see a speed declared as `2.0<m/sec>` (where `m` and `sec` are two separate units of measure previously defined), and a force declared as `5.0<kg m/sec^2>`. (The `kg m/sec^2` would be kg-m/s^2 in "proper" scientific notation, but F# uses the space rather than the hyphen for multiplied units, to avoid any ambiguity since this is *not* subtraction).

Comment: I meant something else still, actually: You can define a UoM type itself in terms of another one: `[<Measure>] type m; [<Measure>] type sqm = m^2` The inferred type for parameters and results will always be `m^2`, but `sqm` can be used as a type alias wherever you give the type yourself.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev another example: `[<Measure>] type N = kg * m * sec ^ -2`.  Is that what you meant?  Then, of course, `let force = 5.0<N>` is the same as `let force = 5.0<kg m/s^2>`.  But then if you multiply by `sec^2` and divide by `kg` you get `N sec^2/kg` rather than `m`.